# How to add Worksheets, after last active sheet, with InputBox?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I implement "count" from the InputBox?

I encountered a syntax error with the below code.

```vb
Sub AddSheets_via_Input_Box()
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Caption As String
    Dim DefValue As Long
    Dim NumSheets As String
    DefValue = 1
    Prompt = "...how many people are working Fraud Today?"
    Caption = "Tell me…"
    NumSheets = InputBox(Prompt, Caption, DefValue)
    Sheets.Add(After:=Temp,Count:=NumSheets)
End Sub
```

Problem starts at:

```
(After:=Temp,Count:=NumSheets)
```

It all works with :

```
Sheets.Add Count:=NumSheets
```

I need those new sheets added after two exiting sheets in that workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't declared `Temp` in your code (if it's a sheet's code name then you need to let us know that also).

Also you can't use parentheses like that in VBA, you only use them when you're grouping something, or evaluating something to return to the left hand side of an expression.

here's a tidied up version:

```
Sub AddSheets_via_Input_Box()

    Dim numberOfSheets As Integer
    '// Here we use parentheses because we are returning a value to numberOfSheets...
    numberOfSheets = CInt(Trim$(InputBox("...how many people are working Fraud Today?", "Tell me…", 1)))

    If IsNumeric(numberOfSheets) Then 
        With ActiveWorkbook
            '// Here we DON'T use parentheses because we aren't returning or evaluating anything...
            .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets("Temp"), Count:= numberOfSheets
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid parameter supplied - use numbers only"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, your code did exactly what I needed. Also, "Temp" indeed was a sheet's code name, sorry for not including that info. If you culd spare a few more minutes I would appreciate you telling me why exactly was my code not working? Was it because "Temp" required to be defined in my version but wasn't?

Comment: Sure (p.s. don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your issue ;) ) - It's because you used parentheses `( )` where they weren't required. VBA is very fickle about this so you can only use parentheses in certain situations with your code. Sheet codenames are scoped at workbook level so you don't need to initialise them as long as your code is in the same workbook.